Howto use a property of a c++ class in a swiftui view
I want to create an application according to MVVM model where my views are programmed in swiftui and my viewmodels are coded in C++. To do that i've done the following things:

Created a swift / swiftui 'hello world' application on my Mac Book Air M2 - MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1

Using xcode 15.4

Imported a C++ library in my application.

Changed the compiler setting for c++ interoperability (see picture).

Changed the searchpad for libraries (see picture).
-xcode compiler settings

my c++ header looks like this:


//
//  BartsCppLibrary.hpp
//  BartsCppLibrary
//
//  Created by BRS on 16/08/2024.
//

#ifndef CppLibrary_
#define CppLibrary_

/* The classes below are exported */
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
#include <string>
class CppLibrary
{
public:
    CppLibrary();
    void IntPlus1(int32_t count);
    std::string text;
    
};

#pragma GCC visibility pop
#endif



my c++ class looks like this:

//
//  BartsCppLibrary.cpp
//  BartsCppLibrary
//
//  Created by BRS on 16/08/2024.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "CppLibrary.hpp"

CppLibrary::CppLibrary()
{
    text="";
    
}

void CppLibrary::IntPlus1(int32_t count)
{
    text=std::to_string(count+1);
    return;
};


My module.map looks like this:

//
//  module.modulemap
//  BartsCppLibrary
//
//  Created by BRS on 16/08/2024.
//

module BartsCppLibrary {
    header "CppLibrary.hpp"
    requires cplusplus
    export BartsCppLibrary
}



my swiftui conentview look like this:

//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by BRS on 11/08/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import BartsCppLibrary


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        @Observable var c = CppLibrary()
    
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("BackgroundColor"))
            .frame (width : 300, height : 200)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            VStack {
                Text("BRS")
                    .font(.title)
                Text ("Title")
                    .italic()
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
                    Text("email")
                }
                HStack
                {
                    Image(systemName: "link")
                    Text("link")

                }
                HStack
                {
                    Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                    Text("Adress")

                }
-->>ERROR-->>                Text(c.text)
            }.padding()
         
        }.frame(width:300, height:200)
         
        }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


And produces an error on the Text(c.Text):
Error:

Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'std.__1.string' (aka 'std.__1.basic_string<CChar, char_traits, allocator>') conform to 'StringProtocol'

I expected that you could use c++ code inside swiftui. Does any one know how to do this?

That’s not how @Observable works (unless this is something new in iOS 18 that I’m not aware of). You must need a Swift type as a bridge.

A std::string does not conform to StringProtocol.  You'll need to use a member variable that conforms to the protocol.  I'm not sure if C++ can conform to protocols.  (Update: you can, link, not sure what all is involved.)  You might need to use Objective-C++ instead.
